# Can I use a lens for Canon EF mount on an EF-S camera body?

Tags: lens, canon, lens-mount, canon-550d

Just a quick question (not too open ended). 
Is the Yongnuo YN 50mm f/1.8 Lens for Canon EF compatible with the Rebel T2i (550D)? And if so, would you recommend the lens?

Thanks in advance for any help.